# Kivy: Create a list of coloured labels using build() method

Tags: python, list, kivy, label

I want to create a list of coloured labels. The thing is that I could do it with the kv file, but I need to do it through the build() method. So I tried replicate what I have done, but it does not work. And I can't understand why.

This is what I've coded

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import *

class RL(RelativeLayout): # Creates the background colour for each label
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(.7, 0, .5, 1)
            Rectangle(size_hint=self.size)

class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    
    N_LBLS = 8
    labels_text = []
    RL_list = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        button = Button(text='do something')
        button.bind(on_release=self.change_text)
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding= 10, spacing = 15)
        for i in range(0, self.N_LBLS):
            self.RL_list.append(RL())
            self.labels_text.append(Label(text=f'{i}º label', size_hint=self.size))
            self.RL_list[i].add_widget(self.labels_text[i])
            box.add_widget(self.RL_list[i])
        self.add_widget(button)
        self.add_widget(box)

    def change_text(self, instance):
        for lbl in self.labels_text:
            if lbl.text[0] == '5':
                lbl.text = 'Text changed'

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

It's supposed to make a button to the left, and a list of 8 coloured labels to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `size_hint=self.size` in each Label. The `self.size` is the size of the `MainMenu`, which is `[100,100]` when that code is executed. Note that [size_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint_x) is a multiplier that is applied to the parents size to calculate the widgets size. So a `size_hint` of `[100,100]` makes each `Label` 100 times bigger than the `MainMenu`. So your code is working, but the `Labels` are so large that the text is off the screen. Start by just removing `size_hint=self.size`.

And, to set a background color on a `Label`, you can just use the `canvas` of that `Label`, rather than some container. Here is a version of your code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class ColorLabel(Label):
    pass


Builder.load_string('''
<ColorLabel>:
    bg_color: [.7, 0, .5, 1]
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.bg_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
''')


class MainMenu(BoxLayout):
    N_LBLS = 8
    labels_text = []

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        button = Button(text='do something')
        button.bind(on_release=self.change_text)
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=10, spacing=15)
        for i in range(0, self.N_LBLS):
            self.labels_text.append(ColorLabel(text=f'{i}º label'))
            box.add_widget(self.labels_text[i])
        self.add_widget(button)
        self.add_widget(box)

    def change_text(self, instance):
        for lbl in self.labels_text:
            if lbl.text[0] == '5':
                lbl.text = 'Text changed'
                lbl.bg_color = [0, 1, 0, 1]


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainMenu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: See updated answer. You can just set a `source=` in the `Rectangle` to specify an image for the background.

Comment: Thank you! Just one more thing. If I wanted to change colours, can I just add this: `self.labels_text[2].canvas = Color(0, .7, .5, 1)` to the `change_text()` method? Or how would i do it?

Comment: See updated answer. I have added a `bg_color` property to the `ColorLabel`, and the `change_text()` method now also changes the background color.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir/lady!